# VNC Veency connection refused

Tags: ios, ipad, vnc

Just jailbroken an iPad on iOS8, installed Veency with Cydia but when I tried to connect to the iPad I got a connection refused. By connection on the iPad with ssh and doing :

```
iPad:~ root#  netstat -a | egrep 'Proto|LISTEN'
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q  Local Address          Foreign Address        (state)
tcp4       0      0  *.ssh                  *.*                    LISTEN
tcp4       0      0  *.62078                *.*                    LISTEN
tcp4       0      0  localhost.intu-ec-clie *.*                    LISTEN
tcp4       0      0  localhost.amt-esd-prot *.*                    LISTEN
tcp4       0      0  localhost.pvuniwien    *.*                    LISTEN
tcp4       0      0  localhost.ansoft-lm-2  *.*                    LISTEN
tcp4       0      0  localhost.socks        *.*                    LISTEN
tcp4       0      0  localhost.ansoft-lm-1  *.*                    LISTEN
```

Nothing is listening on port 5900...
Should it be the problem ? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Veency isn't compatible with iOS 8.x as of this writing. All connection attempts will result in connection refusal. Last known to work with iOS 7.1.2.

**Edit:** [Veency has been updated, includes iOS 8 and 8.1 support](https://twitter.com/saurik/status/544144437786312705)

Comment: Can you add some external documentation for that?  Also, you should note through what version of iOS your answer applies (for legacy readers).

Comment: Thanks Devon! Indeed, for record, see this list https://docs.zoho.com/sheet/published.do?rid=z1v909ff833ece6824400b4d4095ac3a277ac

Comment: @fanzila Veency was updated today, includes iOS 8 and 8.1 support